# C# Retrieve Data From Two Classes

Tags: c#

This was my simple class:

```
public class Location
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Single x { get; set; }
    public Single y { get; set; }
    public Single z { get; set; }
    public float Distance { get; set; }
}
```

I was accessing it like below:

```
public static List<Profile> Loc = ParseXml(); 
var SortedList = Loc.OrderBy(o => o.Distance).ToList();
```

Now, `XML` structure has changed and I have modified my classes like below:

```
public class Profile 
{
    private List<Location> loc = new List<Location>();
    public int Current { get; set; }
    public List<Location> Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Single x { get; set; }
    public Single y { get; set; }
    public Single z { get; set; }
    public float Distance { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to retrieve element from class `Location` which has lowest `ID` under lowest `Current` from `Profile` class.

Comment: Is this useful to have `private List<Location> loc` *and* `public List<Location> Location` ?

Comment: var smallestItem = Loc.OrderBy(o => o.id).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `private List<Location> loc = new List<Location>()` for the `Location` property, you need to change that into non-automatic syntax:

```
public List<Location> Location { get { return loc; } }
```

Note that I removed the setter.

For the Current property to return the closest location, you also need to use real code in the property:

```
public int Current 
{
   get { Loc.OrderBy(o => o.Distance).First().id; }
}
```

Note that this will give an exception if the list is empty! There is also no need to "set" that Current value.